# can not get index of viewcontroller which is viewcontroller of UInavigationController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to check whether  navigation controller's viewcontroller containing ABC Viewcontroller or not  if it  containing want to pop to previous viewcontroller of ABC else want to popviewcontroller

```
class Common:UIViewController{
    class func returnclassviewcontroller(storybordname:String,classname:String)->UIViewController{
        let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: storybordname, bundle: nil)
        var viewcontroller:UIViewController!
        viewcontroller = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: classname)
        return viewcontroller

      }
    }
    if let abcclass = Common.returnclassviewcontroller(storybordname: Constant.StoryboardNameLead, 
              classname: "ABC") as? ABC{

            if(self.navigationController?.viewControllers.contains(abcclass)?? false){
            if let index = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.indexOf(abcclass){

    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController?.viewControllers[index-1] ?? 
    self, animated: true)
    }else{
                              self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)                                           
     }
                            }
                        }else{
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                        }
``
I am reaching to else part everytime , Though ABC Class is in naviagtion constorller's subview controller never reach to "self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController?.viewControllers[index-1] ?? 
    self, animated: true)"
```

Comment: `.firstIndex(of:)` in recent Swift, since 4.2 I think., what's your Swift version? On my code, I get warning: `'index(of:)' is deprecated: renamed to 'firstIndex(of:)'`, with example of line `[3].index(of: 2)`

Comment: I am also using swift version 4.2

Comment: So use `.firstIndex(of:)` instead of `index(of:)`

Comment: yes its working Thanks

Comment: Though class abc pushed once in UINavigationController can not reach to to "if let index = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.indexOf(abcclass){"

Answer (score 3):

[`index(of element: Element) -> Int?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126950-index) is deprecated .. so use [`firstIndex(of element: Element) -> Int?`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994720-firstindex)

> **firstIndex(of:)**
>
> Returns the first index where the specified value  appears in the
>   collection.

```
 if let index =navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: abcclass) {
     // do what you want to with index
    }
```

Comment: what happened sir ? is there any issue in code you faced ?